# How to hide request parameter value in url using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, url, spring-mvc

I'm working on language changes for my page.when the client clicks on any language, page should load in that particular language. For that I configured springs.xml like this

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

The page was loading fine, when I'm give the url like this, site/companykey?lang=french, 
Now my problem is , I want to hide the param value which I have given ?lang=french.
Is there any way  to hide that value from the url ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

locate the form in jsp/html page in which you have included these tags used for changing locale. change the attribute ***method="POST"***. it will make sure that the parameter will pass to the mapped action class without appearing in the url.

Comment: You may need to alter the jsp/html page a bit more if it was not yet using an HTML form.  jQuery might be useful for that.

Comment: @Martin.. of course. thanks for adding more value to the ans.